# Random Python Syntax Error?

Tags: python, random, syntax, syntax-error

I Keep getting a Random syntax error on my code! I am using python 3.3.2

```
def modestart():
modetype = int(input"""Select a Game Mode:
1 - Standard Selection Mode
2 - Ordered Mode
3 - Random Shuffle Mode!
Or press any other key to exit
""")
loop=True
while loop=True:
    try:
        if modetype == 1:
            loop=False
            standard()
        if modetype == 2:
            loop=False
            ordered()
        if modetype == 3:
            loop=False
            shuffle()
        else:
            loop==True
            print("Please select a valid option")
    except ValueError:
        loop=True
        print("Please select a valid option")
```

The syntax error highlights the whole line after the colon on

```
if modetype == 2:
```

Can anyone please help me and tell me what this is, and how to fix it ?

Comment: What does the syntax error say exactly?

Answer (score 1):

```
loop=True
while loop=True:
```

Don't do this.  It is both a syntax error (you meant `while loop == True`) and unnecessary.  Just do

```
while True:
```

and then `break` when you're done looping.  Note that you seem to be mixing up assignment and equality checking all over the place;

```
    else:
        loop==True
```

You almost certainly just meant to do `loop = True`, though this is explicitly unnecessary since it must already be `True` to get to that point in the code.

Actually, I'm wrong there, but not for a good reason.  I am assuming that you also made a logic error and the second and third `if` statements were meant to be `elif` statements.  As is, if the user inputs "1", the first `if` block fires, then the code looks at the second and third `if` blocks.  Since the third `if` statement is false, the `else` statement for that one fires too, which can't be what you want.

This is one more reason to use `break` over 'softer' loop termination like you've implemented.

Answer (score 0):

`while loop=True:` should be `while loop==True:`

I suspect you dont even get to modetype == 2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while loop==True:
```

or, much better, simply

```
while loop:
```

Comment: @danielbeard I beg to disagree.  If the only while in the code is written as any of the 2 alternatives I propose, it works.  Or at least compiles.

Comment: I agree, I've retracted my statement.